# d3 shrinking radar chart shape using attrTween

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

Hi I'm trying to use attrTween for my radar chart.
I made it happen for arc chart so I wanted to apply the same logic to my radar chart but it didn't work out.

can anyone let me know which part I missed?
I would like to shrink the radar chart on 'click'.

the code is as below.

```
d3.selectAll('.btn').on('click', function(d) {
        let selectedone = d3.select(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
        console.log(selectedone);

        d3.select(`.radar${selectedone}`)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween('d', shrinkRadar(0))

        function shrinkRadar(target) {

            return function(d) {
                console.log(d)
                let interpolate = d3.interpolate(rscale(d.value), target)

                return function(t) {
                    console.log(d.radius);
                    d.radius = interpolate(t)
                    return radarLine(d)
                }
            }
        }

        // .attrTween('d',shrinkRadar(finalvalue))
    })
```

Full code in the following link

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/dypJzmZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radar chart's line functions take an array of data to output a path (line and area fill).  You are attempting, though, to operate the `attrTween` like it's manipulating a single piece of data and not an array.  Take a look at this quick re-write:

```
function shrinkRadar(target) {
    return function(d) {    
        // create an array of interpolators
        // one for each point in the line
        // that run the value from starting to 0
        var interps = d.map( da => d3.interpolate(da.value, target));
        return function(t) {
            // for each point call it's interpolator
            // and re-assign the value
            d.forEach( (da,i) => {
              da.value = interps[i](t);
            });
            // regenerate path with new value
            return radarLine(d)
        }
    }
}
```

Running code:

```js
let margin = {
  top: 100,
  bottom: 100,
  left: 100,
  right: 100
}

let width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);


var data = [
  [ //iPhone
    {
      axis: "Battery Life",
      value: 0.22
    },
    {
      axis: "Brand",
      value: 0.28
    },
    {
      axis: "Contract Cost",
      value: 0.29
    },
    {
      axis: "Design And Quality",
      value: 0.17
    },
    {
      axis: "Have Internet Connectivity",
      value: 0.22
    },
    {
      axis: "Large Screen",
      value: 0.02
    },
    {
      axis: "Price Of Device",
      value: 0.21
    },
    {
      axis: "To Be A Smartphone",
      value: 0.50
    }
  ],
  [ //Samsung
    {
      axis: "Battery Life",
      value: 0.27
    },
    {
      axis: "Brand",
      value: 0.16
    },
    {
      axis: "Contract Cost",
      value: 0.35
    },
    {
      axis: "Design And Quality",
      value: 0.13
    },
    {
      axis: "Have Internet Connectivity",
      value: 0.20
    },
    {
      axis: "Large Screen",
      value: 0.13
    },
    {
      axis: "Price Of Device",
      value: 0.35
    },
    {
      axis: "To Be A Smartphone",
      value: 0.38
    }
  ],
  [ //Nokia Smartphone
    {
      axis: "Battery Life",
      value: 0.26
    },
    {
      axis: "Brand",
      value: 0.10
    },
    {
      axis: "Contract Cost",
      value: 0.30
    },
    {
      axis: "Design And Quality",
      value: 0.14
    },
    {
      axis: "Have Internet Connectivity",
      value: 0.22
    },
    {
      axis: "Large Screen",
      value: 0.04
    },
    {
      axis: "Price Of Device",
      value: 0.41
    },
    {
      axis: "To Be A Smartphone",
      value: 0.30
    }
  ]
];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(['#6678D9', '#61F06C', '#FF36AA'])

var radarChartOptions = {
  w: width,
  h: height,
  margin: margin,
  maxValue: 0.5,
  levels: 5,
  roundStrokes: true,
  color: color
};

//   blue, green pink inorder


RadarChart('.radarChart', data, radarChartOptions)

function RadarChart(id, data, options) {

  let cfg = {
    w: 600,
    h: 600,
    margin: {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    },
    levels: 3,
    maxValue: 0,
    labelFactor: 1.25,
    wrapWidth: 60,
    opacityArea: 0.35,
    dotRadius: 4,
    opacityCircles: 0.1,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    roundStroke: false,
    color: ['#6678D9', '#61F06C', '#FF36AA']
  }

  if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
    for (var i in options) {
      if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) {
        cfg[i] = options[i];
      }
    } //for i
  } //if

  //   결론적으로 options에 들어가있는 녀석과 함수에있는 녀석을 매치시키는것
  var maxValue =

    // Math.max(cfg.maxValue,

    d3.max(data,
      (i) => d3.max(
        i.map((o) => o.value)
        // 벨류로 이루어진 어레이를 만들고, 그 어레이에서 최대값을 출력해낸다.
      )
    )
  // )


  var allAxis = data[0].map((d) => {
    return d.axis
  })

  var total = allAxis.length,
    radius = Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2),
    Format = d3.format('%'),
    angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total

  var rscale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, radius])
    .domain([0, maxValue])

  d3.select(id).select('svg').remove()

  var svg = d3.select(id).append('svg')
    .attr('width', cfg.w + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
    .attr('height', cfg.h + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
    .attr('class',
      'radar' + id);

  var g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${cfg.w/2+cfg.margin.left},${cfg.h/2+cfg.margin.top})`)

  var filter = g.append('defs').append('filter').attr('id', 'glow')
  var feGaussianBlur = filter.append('feGaussianBlur').attr('stdDeviation', '2.5')
    .attr('result', 'coloredBlur')
  var feMerge = filter.append('feMerge')
  var feMergeNode1 = feMerge.append('feMergeNode').attr('in', 'coloredBlur')
  var feMergeNode2 = feMerge.append('feMergeNode').attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')

  var axisGrid = g.append('g').attr('class', 'axisWrapper')

  axisGrid.selectAll('.levels').data(
      d3.range(1, (cfg.levels + 1))
    )
    .join('circle')
    .attr('class', 'gridCircle')
    .attr('r', (d) => {
      return radius / cfg.levels * d
    })
    .style('fill', '#CDCDCD')
    .style('stroke', '#CDCDCD')
    .style('fill-opacity', cfg.opacityCircles)
    .style('filter', 'url(#glow)')

  axisGrid.selectAll('.axisLabel')
    .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1))
    .join('text')
    .attr('class', 'axisLabel')
    .attr('x', 4)
    .attr('y', (d) => {
      return -d * radius / cfg.levels
    })
    .attr('dy', '0.4em')
    .style('font-size', '10px')
    .attr('fill', '#737373')
    .text((d, i) => {
      return Format(maxValue * d / cfg.levels)
    })

  var axis = axisGrid.selectAll('.axis')
    .data(allAxis)
    .join('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')

  axis.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

  axis.append("text")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d
    })
    .call(wrap, cfg.wrapWidth)
  // .call(testfunc, 'testString')

  var radarLine = d3.radialLine()
    .radius(function(d) {

      return rscale(d.value)
    })
    .angle(function(d, i, t) {

      return i * angleSlice
    })
    .curve(d3.curveCardinalClosed)

  // if (cfg.roundStrokes) {
  //     radarLine.interpolate("cardinal-closed");
  // }

  const blobWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarWrapper")
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
    .attr("class", "radarWrapper");

  blobWrapper
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "radarArea")
    .attr("d", function(d) {

      return radarLine(d)

    })
    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
      return `radar${i}`
    })
    .style("fill", (d, i) => cfg.color(i))
    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
    .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
      d3.selectAll('.radarArea').transition().duration(200)
        .style('fill-opacity', 0.1)
      d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style('fill-opacity', cfg.opacityArea);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      //Bring back all blobs
      d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
    });


  blobWrapper.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'radarStroke')
    .attr('d', radarLine)
    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
      return `radarStroke${i}`
    })
    .style('stroke', (d, i) => cfg.color(i))
    .style('stroke-width', cfg.strokeWidth + 'px')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('filter', 'url(#glow)')

  let round = 0;

  blobWrapper.selectAll(".radarCircle")
    .data(data)
    .data(function(d) {
      return d
    })
    .join('circle')
    .attr("class", "radarCircle")
    .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d, i, j) {
      if (i == 0) {
        round = round + 1;;
      }
      return cfg.color(round - 1);
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

  var blobCircleWrapper = g.selectAll('.radarCircleWrapper')
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
    .attr('class', 'radarCircleWrapper')

  blobCircleWrapper.selectAll('circles').data(function(d) {
      return d
    })
    .join('circle').attr('class', 'invisibleCircles')
    .attr('r', cfg.dotRadius * 1.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
      return rscale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('pointer-events', 'all')
    .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
      newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
      newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 10;

      tooltip
        .attr('x', newX)
        .attr('y', newY)
        .text(Format(d.value))
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style('opacity', 1);


    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.transition().duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });

  var tooltip = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  d3.selectAll('.btn').on('click', function(d) {
    let selectedone = d3.select(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
    console.log(selectedone);

    d3.select(`.radar${selectedone}`)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween('d', shrinkRadar(0))

    function shrinkRadar(target) {

      return function(d) {
        var interps = d.map(da => d3.interpolate(da.value, target));
        return function(t) {
          d.forEach((da, i) => {
            da.value = interps[i](t);
          });
          return radarLine(d)
        }
      }
    }

    // .attrTween('d',shrinkRadar(finalvalue))
  })

}

function wrap(text, width) {

  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      x = text.attr("x"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.radarChart {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}

.buttonwrap {
    margin-left: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    /* border: dashed grey 0.5px; */
}

.btn {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px navy;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg class="radarChart"></svg>

<div class="buttonwrap">
  <div class="btn 0">Show 1</div>
  <div class="btn 1">Show 2</div>
  <div class="btn 2">show 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for super clear explanation. Now I started to see better picture between plotting an array data set like the case of drawing line and plotting set of data in the case of radar line or plotting circles etc.